# Cannot set config data_dir pear installation with xampp

Tags: pear, phing

I've installed phing with my actual xampp release. If I call my build-file with `./phing` I get the error that my pear data_dir is incorrect. Then I try pear config-set data_dir c:/my_path. I get the information that the operation succeeded and after the next ping-call I get the same error with the old path.

Why I can't update my path?

Thanks!